# SwiftUI - How do I know when the back button of a navigation view has been clicked?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Here's the situation: I want to call a closure when the view is dismissed through the back button. Kind of like `ViewWillDisappear` but for SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple actually. I just had to wrap my view with a call to `onDisappear` and put the closure I was going to call inside.

Comment: The downside is that it has a slight delay and will be called when the caller view is already shown again. I was using it to post-process entries I made in the subview and e.g. removing duplicates. Hitting back shows the entered list in caller view with dupes, then after half a second you see dupes disappear. I ended up overwriting the back button to have a better control.